# Spring Data MongoDB @query for integer value

Tags: mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to use @query for my mongoDB repository interface, to query based on a int32 value.

```
metadata.refObjectId is an int32.

@Repository
public interface ContractRepository extends MongoRepository<ContractDBType, String> {
    @Query(value = "{ 'metadata.refObjectId' : ?0 }")
    List<ContractDBType> getContractByRefObjectId(int refObjId);
}
```

The problem is the above query does not work. 
It works only after I change the field type to String, and then change the query accordingly.

```
metadata.refObjectId change to type String 

@Repository
public interface ContractRepository extends MongoRepository<ContractDBType, String> {
    @Query(value = "{ 'metadata.refObjectId' : ?0 }")
    List<ContractDBType> getContractByRefObjectId(String refObjId);
}
```

What should I do if I want to keep the field type as int32?

Comment: Refobjectid is the primary key of contract class?

Comment: No, RefObjectId is NOT the primary key. It refers an object resides in a SQL DB.